# Is there a difference between variable and function call in template if the function just returning text?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Currently, I want to create an array with the objects where the object has a function that should be called in the template, and in almost all of the cases that function will return simple text without any conditions or any hard logic.

can be there some performance impact, if the function will return simple text without any conditions or any logic.

here is a simple example where I would use it

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-table-example?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts

Comment: In general is better that your "value" was a simple string, then you can write,e.g. `element[item.value]`. If you want to make a "transform" is better you transform the "dataSource", e.g. `dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA.map(x=>({...x,position:x.position.toString().padStart(2, "0")}))`

Comment: @Eliseo I can have the different logics for each item for example? the examples can be more, it is a simple padStart() for transforming

Comment: 1. for example: the item value can be contatanation of 2 field values, also in that case I can show wrong values in case of the value of the field will be changed

Answer (score 1):

yes there can be performance impact because function call every time there is change detection in angular which can be many times. if you still want to use this you can use OnPush change detection which will reduce number of time function calls from template

Comment: xthe material table is optimized inside and it will rerender in case of dataSoruce reference changes, yeah Also almost all of the cases that component which will have the table side will be onPush. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The question is, is there an any difference between function call or variable binding if both will just return the simple string?

Comment: The difference is function will be executed on every change detection even if it returns a simple string. you can avoid that by using pure pipe which will be called on input change only like variables

Comment: but if the template will be re-render it will re-render the text as well,

Answer (score 1):

Complementary my comment. In general when we has an array of object that we can show it's better transform the array than use a function in the .html because in this way we sure than we call to the function "transform" only one time.

if our array is

```
myArray:[{name:...,other:...},{name:...,other:...}..]
```

We can, e.g.

```
this.myArray.forEach(x=>{
    x.name=x.name+' '+x.other //e.g. you concatenate
    x.anotherProperty=this.calculate(x)  //create a new property using a function
    ...what ever we want...
})
```

Or use map

it's better that use a

```
<!--this has a poor performance-->
<div *ngFor="element of myArray">
    {{element.name+' '+element.other}}
    {{calculate(element)}}
</div>
```

You can check adding in the function "calculate" a `console.log`.

In the first aproach, the function "calculate" is executed only the number of elements of the array. Compare with the times is called in the second aproach.

Well, you can "play" with [ChangeDetectionRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) (but it's complicate the app) or acept the "poor performance" (really if you don't have a laaaarge number of elements or the function is very complex you generally don't notice about this)

Comment: So, when the name will be changed dynamically I need to manually update the field value in the array. also, if the template will be re-rendered it will re-render the text as well, just you can't add a console log for checking that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a performance impact in the case of using pure pipes in the value function. Thanks, @Eliseo for the alternative option, I will think about the integration of that one.